# Concatenating all variables in an observation in SAS

Tags: sas

Is there a general purpose way of concatenating each variable in an observation into one larger variable whilst preserving the format of numeric/currency fields in terms of how it looks when you do a proc print on the dataset. (see sashelp.shoes for example)

Here is some code you can run, as you can see when looking at the log, using the catx function to produce a comma separated output removes both the $ currency sign as well as the period from the numeric variables

```
proc print data=sashelp.shoes (obs=10);

run;
proc sql;
 select name into :varstr2 separated by ','
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname = "SASHELP" and
 memname = "SHOES";

 quit;


data stuff();

  format all $5000.;

  set sashelp.shoes ;

  all = catx(',',&varstr2.) ;

  put all;
  run;
```

Any solution needs to be general purpose as it will run on disparate datasets with differently formatted variables.

Comment: What is the goal of this?  Note that CATX() will skip the missing values. Do you really want that?

Comment: Can you check the answers and mark correct one:)

Comment: Please mark correct answer

Answer (score 2):

You can manually loop over PDV variables of the data set, concatenating each formatted value retrieved with `vvaluex`.  A hash can be used to track which variables of the data set to process.  If you are comma separating values you will probably want to double quote formatted values that contain a comma.

```
data want;
  set sashelp.cars indsname=_data;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash vars();
    length _varnum 8 _varname $32;
    vars.defineKey('_n_');
    vars.defineData('_varname');
    vars.defineDone();
    _dsid = open(_data);
    do _n_ = 1 to attrn(_dsid,'NVAR');
      rc = vars.add(key:_n_,data:varname(_dsid,_n_));
    end;
    _dsid = close(_dsid);
    call missing (of _:);
  end;

  format weight comma7.;

  length allcat $32000 _vvx $32000;
  do _n_ = 1 to vars.NUM_ITEMS;
    vars.find();
    _vvx = strip(vvaluex(_varname));
    if index(_vvx,",") then _vvx = quote(strip(_vvx));
    if _n_ = 1 
      then allcat = _vvx;
      else allcat = cats(allcat,',',_vvx);
  end;

  drop _:;
run;
```

Comment: You seem have invented more complicated replacement for the `call vnext()` function

Comment: Perhaps, but `call vnext` will also return automatic variables such as `_n_` `_error_` `first.<var>` `last.<var>` `_I_` that would have to be filtered out.

Comment: Normally you would stop the loop before you hit those automatic variables as they always appear after the actual data step variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution with vvalue and concat function (||)**:

It is similar with 'solution without catx' (the last one), but it is simplified by *vvalue* function instead *put*.

```
/*edit sashelp.shoes with missing values in Product as test-cases*/
proc sql noprint;
   create table wocatx as
   select * from SASHELP.SHOES; 
   update wocatx
   set Product = '';
quit;


/*Macro variable for concat function (||)*/
proc sql;
 select ('strip(vvalue('|| strip(name) ||'))') into :varstr4 separated by "|| ',' ||"
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname = "WORK" and
 memname = "WOCATX";
 quit;


/*Data step to concat all variables*/
data stuff2;
  format all $5000.;
  set work.wocatx ;
  all = &varstr4. ;
  put all;
run;
```

**Solution with catx**:

```
proc print data=SASHELP.SHOES;

run;


proc sql;
 select ifc(strip(format) is missing,strip(name),ifc(type='num','put('|| strip(name) ||','|| strip(format) ||')','input('|| strip(name) ||','|| strip(format) ||')')) into :varstr2 separated by ','
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname = "SASHELP" and
 memname = "SHOES";
 quit;


data stuff();

  format all $5000.;

  set sashelp.shoes ;

  all = catx(',',&varstr2.) ;

  put all;
run;
```

If there isn't in `dictionary.columns` format, then in macro variable varstr2 will just name, if there is format, then when it would call in catx it will convert in format, that you need, for example,if variable is num type then `put(Sales,DOLLAR12.)`, or if it char type then `input` function . You could add any conditions in `select into` if you need.

If there is no need of using of `input` function just change select:

```
ifc(strip(format) is missing,strip(name),'put('|| strip(name) ||','|| strip(format) ||')')
```

**Solution without catx:**

```
/*edit sashelp.shoes with missing values in Product as test-cases*/
proc sql noprint;
   create table wocatx as
   select * from SASHELP.SHOES; 
   update wocatx
   set Product = '';
quit;

/*Macro variable for catx*/
proc sql;
 select ifc(strip(format) is missing,strip(name),ifc(type='num','put('|| strip(name) ||','|| strip(format) ||')','input('|| strip(name) ||','|| strip(format) ||')')) into :varstr2 separated by ','
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname = "WORK" and
 memname = "WOCATX";
 quit;

/*data step with catx*/
data stuff;
  format all $5000.;
  set work.wocatx ;
  all = catx(',',&varstr2.) ;
  put all;
run;

/*Macro variable for concat function (||)*/
proc sql;
 select ifc(strip(format) is missing,
            'strip(' || strip(name) || ')',
            'strip(put('|| strip(name) ||','|| strip(format) ||'))') into :varstr3 separated by "|| ',' ||"
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname = "WORK" and
 memname = "WOCATX";
 quit;


/*Data step without catx*/
data stuff1;
  format all $5000.;
  set work.wocatx ;
  all = &varstr3. ;
  put all;
run;
```

**Result with catx and missing values:**

[image: catx]

**Result without catx and with missing values:**

[image]

Comment: is there a way to not output a period for missing fields, so instead of A,B.,C  we would have A,B,,D

Comment: @user2699504 try to add before code:   options missing=“”;

Comment: CATX() will not generate adjacent delimiters when a value is blank. Instead if just doesn't generate anything for that value.  So `catx(',','a',' ','b')` results in `a,b` and not `a,,b`.

Comment: @Tom ok, may be it is reinventing the wheel, but we can change the missing value, for example “empty” for char value, or “0” for num value for data step before use it. I agree that it isn’t the best way to solve the problem. I will think about it later:)

Comment: And in addition, we can create user written format for those solution(it is just hypothesis, I need to try and test it)

Comment: And again, I have new idea @Tom . We can create macro variable like “|| put() || name || put() .... ” I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: You also need to code for possibility that values contain the delimiter character. Otherwise the resulting string cannot be unpacked.

Comment: You could simplify by using VVALUE() function. Make sure to use a delimiter not included in the data.  `select cats('strip(vvalue(',name,'))')  into :varlist separated by "||'|'||"` ...  `length all $5000.;  all = &varlist ;`

Comment: @Tom thank you, for remarks. I will try it, and in case of success will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use import and export to csv file:

```
filename tem temp;
proc export data=sashelp.SHOES file=tem dbms=csv replace;
run;

data l;
length all $ 200;
infile tem   truncover firstobs=2;
input all  1-200;
run;
```

P.S.
If you need concatenate only char, uou can create array of all CHARACTER columns in dataset, and just iterate thru:

```
data l;
length all $ 5000;
set sashelp.SHOES;
array ch [*] _CHARACTER_;
do i = 1 to dim(ch);
    all=catx(',',all,ch[i]);
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PUT` statement is the easiest way to do that.  You don't need to know the variables names as you can use the `_all_` variable list.

```
put (_all_) (+0);
```

It will honor the formats attached the variables and if you have used DSD option on the FILE statement then the result is a delimited list.

What is the ultimate goal of this exercise?  If you want to create a file you can just write the file directly.

```
data _null_;
   set sashelp.shoes(obs=3);
   file 'myfile.csv' dsd ;
   put (_all_) (+0);
run;
```

If you really do want to get that string into a dataset variable there is no need to invent some new function. Just take advantage of the `PUT` statements abilities by creating a file and then reading the lines from the file.

```
filename junk temp;
data _null_;
   set sashelp.shoes(obs=3);
   file junk dsd ;
   put (_all_) (+0);
run;
data stuff ;
  set sashelp.shoes(obs=3);
  infile junk truncover ;
  input all $5000.;
run;
```

[image]

You can even do it without creating the full text file. Instead just write one line at a time and save the line into a variable using the `_FILE_` automatic variable.

```
filename junk temp;
data stuff;
  set sashelp.shoes(obs=3);
  file junk dsd lrecl=5000 ;
  length all $5000;
  put @1 (_all_) (+0) +(-2) '  ' @;
  all = _file_;
  output;
  all=' ';
  put @1 all $5000. @;
run;
```

Comment: I don't want to write a file!. In fact I do not have permission to write files from SAS. When I concatenate the fields together, missing fields get represented by a period character. Can it be made so that nothing is output for a missing field (without writing files!). So instead of A,B.,.,.,.,.,Y I get A,B,,,,,Y

 

Also a supplementary question. Does the field separator have to be a printable character. Can it be something like a control character such as CTRL-A

Comment: No need to make an actual file. See updates.  You can use the `DLM=` option on the `FILE` statement to set any character you want as the delimiter.

Comment: Good use of automatic variable `_file_` to capture the output line.  You might want to try to file to `/dev/null` (Unix) or `NUL` (Windows) and prevent any actual disk writing.

Comment: I wonder if any I/O ever happens when using the trailing @ other than at the end of the step.